# Eliminate duplicate code snippets in PL/SQL function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need help/advice on optimizing my function. How can I avoid duplicating this fragment of code:

```sql
    select 1 from order_attr oa
    where oa.order_id = o.order_id and ea.order_attr_name = 'administrationId'
```

My PL/SQL function below (this is an example, **in real code the fragment is repeated many times**):

```sql
   begin
   select count (distinct o.order_id)
   into :result
   from orders o
   where o.ext_order_id = :ExtOrderId and o.service_id not like 'tech#%' and (:Include = 1 and exists
   (
      select 1 from order_attr oa
      where oa.order_id = o.order_id and ea.order_attr_name = 'administrationId'  
   )
   or :Include = 0 and not exists
   (
      select 1 from order_attr oa
      where oa.order_id = o.order_id and ea.order_attr_name = 'administrationId' 
   ));
   exception
   when others then
      :result := 0;
   end;
```

Comment: You could try to put it in the cte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the left join is what will help you here

```
 from orders o
 left join order_attr oa 
   on oa.order_id = o.order_id and ea.order_attr_name = 'administrationId'  
where o.ext_order_id = :ExtOrderId and o.service_id not like 'tech#%' 
  and (:Include = 1 and oa.order_id is not null -- exists
   or :Include = 0 and oa.order_is is null; -- not exists
```

I don't have data to test, but I hope you'll get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that you may or may not like :-)

First of all, the `order_id` should be the unique identifier of an order. So I'd change `count(distinct o.order_id)` to `count(*)`, because there are no nulls to skip; we just want to count order rows.

About the same goes for order attributes; `order_attr` seems to be a key/value table, where for some reason orders can be so very different from each other that they need different columns, which is why you have this table. There must not be two rows for the same attribute in an order. Having said this, you can just count how many administration IDs the order has, and it will be 0 or 1.

```
begin
   select count(*))
   into :result
   from orders o
   where o.ext_order_id = :ExtOrderId and o.service_id not like 'tech#%' 
   and :Include = 
   (
      select count(*) from order_attr oa
      where oa.order_id = o.order_id and ea.order_attr_name = 'administrationId'  
   );
   exception
   when others then
      :result := 0;
   end;
```

If I am wrong and for some reason you can have multiple administration IDs per order, then just add `and rownum = 1` to the subquery in order to still end up wth a count of 0 or 1.